# CSS Invalid Property Value

Tags: html, css

Bueno he estado haciendo un proyecto que encontré en un curso online y todo muy bien, pero, necesito centrar un botón. En el vídeo utilizan el las siguientes lineas:

```
div.resumen input{
  display: block;
  margin-bottom:  10px auto;
}
```

En el tutorial funciona pero a la hora de yo ejecutarlo me aparece

```
"Invalid Property Value"
```

**¿Aluien me puede decir por qué ocurre y como solucionarlo?**

Comment: ¿Sobre qué HTML intentas aplicar ese código?

Comment: Estás poniéndole 2 valores a `margin-bottom` que sólo puede tomar un valor. ¿Seguro que quieres hacer `margin-bottom` y no simplemente `margin`?

Answer (score 1):

Es cierto, estás pasándole dos valores a margin bottom, lo que podrías hacer es establecer un valor para margin bottom dentro de margin:

```
div.resumen input{
  display: block;
  margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px auto; /*top - right - bottom - left - auto*/
}
```

Epero te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Estás poniéndole 2 valores a `margin-bottom` que sólo puede tomar un valor: un longitud, un porcentaje o `auto`. Pero solo uno de ellos. Entonces lo correcto sería:

```
div.resumen input{
  display: block;
  margin-bottom:  10px; /* quitando el auto */
}
```

Este error puede ocurrir porque en lugar de `margin-bottom` lo que quieres cambiar es `margin` (que sí admite 1-4 valores) o que antes había un `margin` y ahora es sólo `margin-bottom` (me ha pasado varias veces cambiando código CSS :S).

Fuentes:

- [Artículo de MDN para `margin-bottom`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/margin-bottom) (parcialmente en español)
- [Definición de los bordes en el estándar de CSS](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties) (en inglés)